# Is redis client using the long connection

Tags: connection, redis

Is redis client using the long connection? If it wasn't long connection, why not use long link to reduce the cost of establishing a connection

Answer (score 3):

Redis [clients](http://redis.io/topics/clients) use [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) connection which is persisted until either side terminates it therefore it's up to the client library how the connection will be handled. I assume most of the clients would try to leave the established connection (or multiple connections in case of a pool) open during the lifetime of application where they are used in order to prevent handshaking before each executed command.